# Use variables when saving objects in Django

Tags: python, django, variables

In Django, is there a way to identify which attribute of an object I want to edit by using a POST/GET variable instead of explicitly naming it?

For example, I want to do this:

```
def edit_user_profile(request):
    field_to_edit = request.POST.get('id')
    value = request.POST.get('value')
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    user.field_to_edit = strip_tags(value);
    user.save()
```

instead of this:

```
def edit_user_profile(request):
    value = request.POST.get('value')
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    user.first_name = strip_tags(value);
    user.save()
```

Comment: There's no reason to write `user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)` -- `request.user` is already a `User` object

Answer (score 3):

Gabi's answer is exactly what you want. You could use `setattr` instead though:

```
setattr(user, field_to_edit, strip_tags(value))
```

Which is (very very slightly!) more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getattr` function:

```
getattr(user, field_to_edit) = strip_tags(value)
```